# scheduling event in php or using AWS of similar web technology

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, job-scheduling

I have three tasks A, B, C. When task A performed, I want to schedule task B to be run after X(variable) hours. What is the best way for this? Is there any specific AWS service for this? Currently, I am storing in schedule activity in the database and running CRON over it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your short description, it appears that [Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html) would be good choice:

> Step Functions provides a reliable way to **coordinate components** and step through the functions of your application.

With SF you can build a **state machine** using variety of actions. For example, since you require task B to be run after X hours after task A, you could use [wait](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html) to enable that.

What's more since you are using `cron`, you could replace it with [CloudWatch Event Schedule Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) rule which would periodically trigger your SF workflow. Scheduled expressions support `cron` expressions which would make porting your existing `cron` job easier.